# Damage Source File due to Cancelling Copy Paste

Tags: mac, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, copy-paste, file-corruption

I was copying some 20gb of important documents to my usb drive from my mac. The process got stuck midway and I had to cancel the copy paste operation. Second time doing so the usb drive got ejected by itself. I later found out that the usb drive is faulty and needs to be replaced.

My question is since I was copying the files from Mac Air 2020, mac os Monterey to my USB C pen drive, and the operation of copy paste was cancelled twice, will it by any chance effect my source/original files from which the data was being copied.

My concern is - is the original/ source file damaged or corrupted by any chance due to abortion of the copy paste operation and then pendrive being ejected midway. I dont want my source files to be corrupted since I have many subfolder and important documents.

Please help to convince me that cancelling of copy paste does no damage to the source file on my mac.

Thanks

Comment: why would a copy operation alter the source file?

Answer (score 0):

No chance of damage whatsoever.
This is also why Mac doesn't have a cut operation in the Finder - it has Move, which makes sure the entire write operation was successful before deleting the original.